# How to build a library from AOSP?

Tags: android, android-ndk, android-source

I need to build [libjpeg-turbo](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/external/libjpeg-turbo/) library which is from android AOSP.

The repository contains this **Android.bp** file, and i have no idea how to build it. Before this, all of the libraries i've built had **Android.mk** file inside **JNI** folder and for the building i was using **ndk-build** command. 
How can i succesfully build this library?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some while ago, NDK and AOSP configuration scripts (Android.mk) looked very similar. Historically, NDK used the AOSP build system (based on GNU make). Since these early days, evolution of the two build systems went in different directions, and culminated in recent switch of AOSP to blueprint build system.

But even before this, you could use **ndk-build** with AOSP **Android.mk** files only occasionally. Many libraries, especially libraries with dependencies, could not be built this way.

Luckily, libjpeg-turbo is one of the subprojects of AOSP that don't have problematic dependencies. If you [step back](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/external/libjpeg-turbo/+/fc5b9cef2ae644ca0a9e48e38d668ac38e7fc899) in git history for this library, you will be able to build it with **ndk-build**. You can even cherry-pick the relevant changes to your NDK-compatible branch.

Alternatively, you can use the [official libjpeg-turbo repository](https://libjpeg-turbo.org/) instead of AOSP tree.